# PaperPort Won't Scan from ONE Unprivileged Account

Tags: windows-7, scanner

I'm running PaperPort at my parents' office for them to scan. We have Xerox DocuMate 162 scanners, hooked up to each workstation that needs to scan. For one of the workstations, ONE of the unprivileged accounts cannot scan. The "Scan" button is grey'd out in PaperPort. For another unprivileged account, on the same machine, scanning is possible. Additionally, from the account that cannot scan, if I run the application as an Administrator, then "scan" isn't grey'd out. If I cannot actually solve this, then running the scanning application as administrator will solve the problem of having to logout, scan, move the document, and log back in, when one of the workers wants to scan something.

I ran the [PPScnConnTool](http://supportcontent.nuance.com/paperport/14/PPScnConnTool.exe) (PaperPort's connection tool) and all the connections checked out fine.

As I am a [hardcore programmer](http://www.noventum.us/#team), with Windows application development experience, [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) did not pick up any problematic .DLL's.

The Windows event log shows nothing, and I do not see any type of file-based logging present for PaperPort.

This sounds exactly like the sort of thing a regular Windows administrator should be dealing with, in a normal office setup...

Comment: Are you 100% sure the account that does work actually isn't an Administrator?

Comment: It works in two other accounts - one that is an administrator, and the other is a standard user. I am sure that one of those is a standard user.

Comment: I uninstalled the application, and reinstalled an older version (running the installer as the user I wanted to be able to access it.) This worked. I'll probably order a replacement installation disc for like $15 to be running the most recent version.

Comment: You should be able to just download the most recent version, and use your license key, provided your license key is to the current version